# htaccess rewrite redirect to non existing page

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am having a bit of trouble with my URL rewrite.

I want to:

1. rewrite urls with params to slashes
2. redirect to rewritten urls.
3. allow for A-Z0-9 directories before test.php in url.  right now /test.php only triggers.

example:

```
 a href="test.php?options=1>Click here</a>
```

when clicked will redirect to url:

```
test/options/1
```

OR

```
abc123/test/options/1  (if the link had abc123/test.php)
```

and this page will open as the actuall test.php

Existing code:

```
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ /test.php?options=$1
RewriteRule  ^test\.php$ /test/options/%1  [L,R=301]
```

Two problems with above code:

1. slashes work, but parameter wont go away at end of url. ?options=xx stays
2. test.php may have directories numbers or letters before it in url. In this case URL Rewrite doesnt trigger.

Comment: for point 2: `^` means "start of string". If you have stuff before "test.php", then you can't have the "start of string" anchor.

Comment: Can you provide a list of example URLs you want to support and also include their actual internal URIs as well.

Comment: So you want to change from search-friendly clean URL's to parametrized URL's?  That is the opposite of what most people try to do.  What is your use case here?

Comment: Is this your complete .htaccess?

Comment: anubhava, sure. the two urls (virtual directories..they dont actually exist) are:  products/test.php?options=1  and items/test.php?options=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply wanted to redirect /test?options={param} to /test/1/ and /test?options={params} to /test you could do this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^test=options$     [NC]
RewriteRule ^/test$             /test/options/     [NC,L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^test=options$    [NC]
RewriteRule ^/blog$             /test/          [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: This is almost perfect. But I have two different virtual directories. How can the Rewrite Condition work for both:

products/test.php?options=1
items/test.php?options=1